# Ruby's narray gem installation error on Windows

Tags: ruby, math, rubygems, installation, narray

I'm trying to install the NArray gem for Ruby to do some math functions. I'm running Ruby version 2.0.0p353 [x64-mingw32] on Windows with gem 2.014

When I attempt to install the NArray gem, it produces the following error:

> D:\DocPerso\Workspace Ruby>gem install narray
>
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> > ERROR:  Error installing narray:
> >
> > ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> >
> > C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> >
> > C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb
> >      (LoadError)
>
> Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.
>   0/gems/narray-0.6.0.8 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/narray-0.6
>   .0.8/src/gem_make.out

I've googled, with no luck whatsoever.

Her you find what I obtain with gem env :

> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
> - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x64-mingw32]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
> > - ruby
> > - x64-mingw32
>
> - GEM PATHS:
>
> > ```
> > - C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
> > ```
>
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
> > ```
> > - :update_sources => true
> >
> > - :verbose => true
> >
> > - :backtrace => false
> >
> > - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> > ```
>
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
> > ```
> > - https://rubygems.org/
> > ```

Comment: Anything relevant in the log: `C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/narray-0.6.0.8/src/gem_make.out`

Comment: not interesting for me but I'm a newbie :                       C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb          C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

Comment: The missing file is effectively a makefile generator. It isn't missing, just not where `gem` expects it. I wonder if the Ruby scripts are unable to change drive automatically, so it's trying to `cd` to the temporary build folder on C:, but stuck on D: - does the fault happen if you run the install starting from a prompt with current dir on C: ?

Comment: I obtain the same error message when I launch the installation with current dir on C:

Comment: I don't know the fault then, sorry. It's a gem I use a lot though, so can confirm the version you are trying to install is not faulty in other environments. In fact I happened to re-install it this morning (but on a Mac, not Windows).

Comment: I manage to install other gems without any problems. But, I obtain the same error when I try to install "rmagick" or "rails" for exemple.

Comment: the gem sourse stay in `C:/Ruby200-x64/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/narray-0.6.0.8`. show list of that folder.

Comment: In this dirctory in find one directory : src and 6 files : Change.Log, MANIFEST, README.en, README.ja, SPEC.en and SPEC.ja

Answer (score 0):

The instructions [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) worked for me.

> `AutoRun`  interferes with Ruby messing with child process executing
>   and by result, affecting gem installation.

For the lazy; remove it with the following commands:

```
REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
REG DELETE "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
```